# Cypher RANGE() function does not yield the correct results

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have about 20m nodes with a certain label with the constraint:

```
// the id is a long
CREATE CONSTRAINT ON (n:LABEL) ASSERT n.id IS UNIQUE;
```

I am trying to efficiently iterate over all the nodes to add a property to all of them, e.g.

```
MATCH (n:LABEL) SET n.prop = <prop_value>
```

According to instructions from [MH](https://stackoverflow.com/users/728812/michael-hunger) 
([here](http://neo4j.com/blog/neo4j-2-2-query-tuning/), Query Tuning Tip #1)
   I have tried to use the RANGE keyword to make use of the constraint index, but I don't get any results, eg

```
//yields the correct result, but scans the whole label, unusable in practice
MATCH (n:LABEL) WHERE n.id >= 10 AND n.id <= 30 RETURN COUNT(*);

//scans the index, but yields 0 !
MATCH (n:LABEL) WHERE n.id IN RANGE(10, 30) RETURN COUNT(*);


// this works 
MATCH (n:LABEL) WHERE n.id = 1125985806188545 RETURN n; 
// these don't work 
MATCH (n:LABEL) WHERE n.id IN RANGE(1125985806188544, 1125985806188546) RETURN n; 
MATCH (n:LABEL) WHERE TOINT(n.id) IN RANGE(1125985806188544, 1125985806188546) RETURN n;
```

Neo 2.2.3 Community, Ubuntu 64bit

**Update:**
It was indeed a bug. After doing more tests, the problem exists in all 2.2.x versions (up to 2.2.8) and it is that range() function was only using ints.
The fix (RangeFunction should use longs instead of ints) was just [merged into 2.2.9 yesterday](https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/pull/6430)

Comment: Are you sure the `id` property is an integer?

Comment: See if `WHERE TOINT(n.id) IN RANGE(10, 30)` works.

Comment: Nope. It seems `TOINT(n.id)` returns nothing ( I only have long numbers in there). Is there any other way of using the index to efficiently iterate over all the nodes?

Comment: I don't follow. `TOINT(n.id)` should return an integer. The only reason I can think of that you'd get results for the first query and not for the second is if `n.id` is a float. A float won't be in the range, e.g. `RETURN 1.5 IN RANGE(0,5);` would return false.

Comment: `id` is a Long. I use this trick to check it
`neo4j-sh (?)$ MATCH (n:LABEL) WHERE n.id = 1125985806188545 RETURN TYPE(n.id);
java.lang.Long cannot be cast to org.neo4j.graphdb.Relationship`

Comment: @Nikos: The [TYPE()](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/query-functions-scalar.html#functions-type) function in Cypher can only be used on a relationship, to get its relationship type.

Comment: @cybersam He was using it incorrectly on purprose to force the error to tell him what the data type is.

Comment: @NicoleWhite Ah. Incorrectly use `TYPE` in order to get the type.  LOL.

Answer (score 0):

You can force the use of the index. Both of these queries *should* do that (tested on version 2.3):

```
MATCH (n:LABEL)
USING INDEX n:LABEL(id)
WHERE n.id >= 1125985806188544 AND n.id <= 1125985806188546
RETURN COUNT(*);
```

and

```
MATCH (n:LABEL)
USING INDEX n:LABEL(id)
WHERE n.id IN RANGE(1125985806188544, 1125985806188546)
RETURN COUNT(*);
```

If you continue to have issues, you should consider updating your neo4j version, as this might have been a problem with version 2.2.3.